How to find code churn information for a certain changeset/commit in Azure DevOps TFVC / GIT
In Azure DevOps Server 2020, a data warehouse existed and was maintained in the tfs_warehouse database. This database contained a FactCodeChurn table that contained the LinesAdded, LinesModified, LinesDeleted and NetLinesAdded columns.
Azure DevOps Server 2022 no longer uses analytics and the tfs_warehouse database.
How to get code churn information for a specific changeset/commit in TFVC / GIT in Azure DevOps Server 2022?

Hi @tibx, Have you got a chance to check the answer by Rui below to use API instead? Hope the workaround may help. Thx.

Hi @Alvin, the question was asked more broadly, i.e. also about the GIT-type repository, but I need to get information about code churn for the TFVC-type repository. So Diffs - Get doesn't seem to solve this problem unfortunately.
In addition, it also appears that the Diffs - Get service returns summary changeCounts (Edit / Add) for all files in the commit, however tfs_warehouse.FactCodeChurn recorded code churn with granularity per file.

I tried to search for some ODATA report or extensions but no luck. It doesn't seem to support the functionality that we need at the moment. For this, you could create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions. Thx for the insights.

It's probably no longer possible to get information about how many lines were added, modified or deleted in a particular file.
But you can use the Diffs - Get endpoint of the Azure DevOps REST API to find the closest common commit (the merge base) between base and target commits, and get the diff between either the base and target commits or common and target commits.
Example - diff between commit IDs c093714168cdd190c1e171a803e996d685454352 and 2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4 in repository my-repo:
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/MyProject/_apis/git/repositories/my-repo/diffs/commits?baseVersion=c093714168cdd190c1e171a803e996d685454352&baseVersionType=commit&targetVersion=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4&targetVersionType=commit&api-version=7.1-preview.1

Sample response:
{
  "allChangesIncluded": true,
  "changeCounts": {
    "Edit": 15,
    "Add": 1
  },
  "changes": [
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "bde769ee42117ea4ea87d5ec29ebdad6d3db90e6",
        "originalObjectId": "5a99d58c0ee5d8ea32a837c0f3e1c384d9b3f35c",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/CustomerAddressModule",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//CustomerAddressModule?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "062c2370b4a773e4d1240d0591f05236ea6bffd5",
        "originalObjectId": "ac01e969c8f57a5ce4404c8314d28c376b9741aa",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/CustomerAddressModule/CustomerAddressModule",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//CustomerAddressModule/CustomerAddressModule?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "44d4defe7505e786c7843bb8d48742fbd7fb2a5d",
        "originalObjectId": "c7b2717ed43cf3a146178efe8c6b56f15e04e206",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/CustomerAddressModule/CustomerAddressModule/Form1.cs",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//CustomerAddressModule/CustomerAddressModule/Form1.cs?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "86611e6e2a985a667b2d744d3e133c035d050fdc",
        "originalObjectId": "1880da2a57cc772c0e8cd1725911e05fb9dea384",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/CustomerAddressModule/CustomerAddressModule/Program.cs",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//CustomerAddressModule/CustomerAddressModule/Program.cs?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "3936f555cbfd2354766c928f24314f3371b26eb9",
        "originalObjectId": "5ae8cdfbac92acedd2516c0cf47cb4e23834c907",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/HelloWorld",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//HelloWorld?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "12ab83fdf67f60340065fd6595f7b7d27ac43e64",
        "originalObjectId": "91ffd59c44444779a707d22dca26481062912771",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/HelloWorld/src",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//HelloWorld/src?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "11c2143a3d6cdf7c183875b1c9bcd9ed1148946b",
        "originalObjectId": "8c372a0d74743a1e6bde482b6ad1b7d3086400cc",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/HelloWorld/src/HelloWorld.java",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//HelloWorld/src/HelloWorld.java?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "5bb6f703f01eba72e9bb023891991f71e611b1e4",
        "originalObjectId": "64e06bc4be939bffe64c65ae3c290e4c5206acf2",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "a1ec6decdcc91b432aadac506db6e56f6d75cc60",
        "originalObjectId": "429e27bd5309b641581aed99ab7c26e3054ed1a0",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "a3237c23ed9a046387ddcacdf3b9c612bc884939",
        "originalObjectId": "0d106d2f98e710ff86c5991991990a2e8f9819bd",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Project_Readme.html",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Project_Readme.html?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "5b029732598033bba1d7e7087b54f3030fe67c09",
        "originalObjectId": "9b8bb976714f08fe5a2b82559a11ce35fa10c3cd",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Startup.cs",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Startup.cs?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "d1d5c2d49045d52bba6419652d6ecb2cd560dc29",
        "originalObjectId": "cdf394b9560d7f9b1c97858d15962504def55642",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "ea6765e1976b9e8a6d4981fd8febebd574a91571",
        "originalObjectId": "de4d162bd8e761438917de6aa79ca0296d42d113",
        "gitObjectType": "tree",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home",
        "isFolder": true,
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "8052a02bee6f82ae02c4d408d1b5b98ab1bf56a6",
        "originalObjectId": "49602fb29a79ea6e70746b1cfccbb080531aa6dc",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Register.cshtml",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Register.cshtml?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "b219db18b7fd7c45b05a0092846a8fbf1edbe18f",
        "originalObjectId": "42f77316b7d166374ce8d6cb9f141b9e77c582f5",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Web.config",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Web.config?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "edit"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "objectId": "f61bddbdf26a6365e02c94531abb370409c5aea3",
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "commitId": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
        "path": "/readme.md",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/c34d5807-1734-4541-ad1c-d16e9ac1faca/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items//readme.md?versionType=Commit&version=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4"
      },
      "changeType": "add"
    }
  ],
  "commonCommit": "c093714168cdd190c1e171a803e996d685454352",
  "baseCommit": "c093714168cdd190c1e171a803e996d685454352",
  "targetCommit": "2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4",
  "aheadCount": 22,
  "behindCount": 0
}

You can also get the diff between branches
